# "Control A to B" is grammatically OK?

Tags: verbs

> This air conditioning controls the room temperature to be equal to a
>   temperature five degrees higher than the outside temperature.

I think "adjust" is better than "control" in this sentence, but would like to know whether the usage of "control" is acceptable.

Comment: *"This air conditioning regulates the temperature in the room so that it is equal to a temperature five degrees higher than the temperature outside."* - But this is nontechnical.

Comment: *Control* sounds very odd to this US English speaker; we don't usually say that X *controls Y to* something.  *Regulate* or *adjust* or *set* would work better.

Comment: I agree, so close this.